# Django redirecting to home after login does not work

Tags: python, django

I am trying to redirect to homepage after login with no sucess

settings.py

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', home, name='home'),
    path('defaultsite', home, name='home'),
]
```

views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render(request, 'general/index.html')
]
```

I do not have a personalized Django login system (usying system default) but nothing seems to work. Changing *LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'* to *LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'* does not work either.

Strangely, *LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'* works like a charm.

Any help?

Using Django 4.1.7 & python 3.10.5

Comment: You need to implement the [default authentication views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#module-django.contrib.auth.views), the admin's login system will not redirect to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` because it's the admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

#### views.py

```
def SigninView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uname = request.POST.get('username')
        upass = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=uname,password=upass)
        if user is None:
            messages.error(request,'Please Enter Correct Credinatial')
            return redirect('/signin/')
        else:
            login(request,user)
            messages.info(request,'Login Successful')
            return redirect('/dashboard/')
    else:
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return redirect('/dashboard/')
        else:
            return render(request,'signin.html')
    return render(request,'signin.html')
```

#### urls.py

```
path('signin/', SigninView, name='signin'),
```

#### HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Enter Username"> <br>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password"> <br> <br>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by myself at the end.

I do not want to use a personalized login page(template), not for the moment at least. So y modified the ***def home*** function:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect('/admin/login/?next=/')

return render(request, 'general/index.html')
```

By view I can force a home redirect after login, something that does not work by settings configuration. I still maintained the working **LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'** in order to the repeat the cycle after logout